# Saving a dataframe from Databricks is really slow

Tags: sql, dataframe, databricks

I am working on an ML project, and I am now investigating the training data. The data is stored in Databricks and it's taking hours to download a dataset with a few thousand lines. This is the approach I am following:

1. Build a dataframe by selecting the table values I'm interested in. Time: 0.07 sec.
2. Simplify the dataframe. Time: 0.08 sec.
3. Save the dataframe using `df.coalesce(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").save`. Time: 1h and counting.

Do you have any suggestion on how I could speed up the process? Ideally, I would like to repeat the steps a few thousand times.

Here are my commands:

```
%py
table_name = 'coordinates'
df = spark.sql (f"""select * from main_frame where event_date = '2023-01-18' and session_unique_id = '34eb1a29-aebb-4425-9997-7074e45244e9'""")

df1 = df \
 .select('character.accountid', 'character.health')

df1.coalesce(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").save("dbfs:/FileStore/user/me/logpos.csv")
```

Comment: I am wondering if `select accountid, health` would help? You can merge SQL and select commands.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! It looks like things don't change much: it still takes a lot of time to load all rows so that the csv can be downloaded / save the csv.

Comment: Just to see if it makes any difference, can you maybe try below options ? 1. save df1 to a temp table or something  - Query the table `%sql select * from table` Considering that you have less than 1000 records - you should be able to download the CSV from the UI itself...2. Also you could try to check if coalesce is causing the slowdown by removing it - let it write to n number of files and then concatenate them in a %sh cell

Comment: For posterity: I ended up doing all the processing steps on Databricks. I could not find any easy way for exporting data.